# Circle rotation of squares. Phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

The following code rotates the pictures in a circle

```js
function create() {
  followers = this.add.container();

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let ball = followers.create(0, 0, 'ball').setScale(0.7);
    ball.setData('vector', new Phaser.Math.Vector2());

    lal = this.tweens.add({
      targets: ball,
      z: -1,
      ease: 'Linear',
      duration: 12370,
      repeat: -1,
      delay: i * 320
    });
  }
}

function update() {
  balls = followers.getChildren();

  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    let t = balls[i].z;
    let vec = balls[i].getData('vector');

    curve.getPoint(t, vec);
    balls[i].setPosition(vec.x, vec.y);
    balls[i].setDepth(10);
  }

  followers.setDepth(10)
}
```

**How can i make squares of unlimited number rotate in a circle?** For example, so that 10 squares rotate in a circle in the same way as pictures